# Objective C paging enabled UIScrollView content offset is off after changing size of the frame

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with paging enabled.  After I change the view from landscape to portrait (and vice versa) I change the frame size and I want the contents inside to "snap" to the new frame size.  Right now the content offset is stuck from the previous frame size. However, when I scroll after a frame change it will snap to the correct offset.  I tried to set the content offset after a frame size change but it still wouldn't snap to the new frame.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Sorry if this is not clear.

Comment: Have you tried calling `setNeedsLayout` after changing the frame size?

Comment: Yeah I tried that and no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just doing my math wrong when trying to setContentOffset.

```
CGFloat x = (self.thumbnails.pageControl.currentPage * self.thumbnails.scrollView.frame.size.width);
[self.thumbnails.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x,0)];
```